# How to calculate quantile and variance for the tensorflow_probability output?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, confidence-interval, tensorflow-probability

I test the following code:

[TFP Probabilistic Layers: Regression](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/probability/blob/master/tensorflow_probability/examples/jupyter_notebooks/Probabilistic_Layers_Regression.ipynb#scrollTo=5zCEYpzu7bDX)

In "**Custom PSD Kernel**" section, I got `yhat` as the prediction for the test data.

My purpose is to have a confidence interval for this prediction. If I want to calculate the variance or quantile for this prediction with the `variance` and `quantile` methods, respectively, I will get the following error:

- **NotImplementedError**: variance is not implemented: TransformedDistribution
- **NotImplementedError**: quantile is not implemented: Independent

Therefore my question is:

**How can I obtain the confidence interval for this prediction?**

I need something like the following picture [Confidence Interval for the prediction (yhat.mean())]:

[image: Confidence Interval for the prediction (yhat.mean())]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: have you found a solution ?